# pandas gbq - DistributionNotFound error

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I am having trouble using the google bigquery package in pandas. I have installed the google-api-python-client as well as the pandas-gbq packages. But for some reason when I go to query a table I get a `DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application` error. Here is a snippet of my code:

`import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import gbq`

`count_block = gbq.read_gbq('SELECT count(int64_field_0) as count_blocks FROM Data.bh', projectid)`

Comment: are you using a VE and have multiple versions of Python installed? Did you use PIP to install?

Comment: @GrahamPolley, Nope not using any VE and only have 3.6 installed. Yup, I used pip to install

Comment: Using a virtual environment and the packages you describe I didn't get this error. Perhaps you could try using a virtual environment to rule out some problem with the installed libraries?

Comment: @ChristopherP , that did the job!! I thought of that before I asked the question but didn't actually do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a virtual environment in this scenario can allow you to rule out problems with your library installations

Comment: totally agree. I am going to start using them more often. Thanks!!